# Sync a folder with tar without recreating the tar

Tags: bash, sh, tar

Im trying to write a script that keeps a tar in sync with a folder. I am dealing with a lot of files and don't want to remake the tar every time the script is run. I want it to only add/remove files from the tar that have been added/removed from the folder since the last script run. Here's what I have.

```
# Create tar if it doesn't exist but don't over write if it does exist
touch -a /home/MyName/data.tar

cd /home/MyName

# Make the tar
tar -uv --exclude='dirToTar/FileIWantToExclude' -f $tarFile dirToTar
```

This works great for adding files. But if a file is deleted from `dirToTar`, it doesn't get removed from `data.tar`.

Comment: You need the `--delete` flag to remove a file from an archive. Also using `-u` is storing a second copy of the updated files in the archive which uses more disk space over tim).

Comment: Thanks. Is there something I can do instead of -u to save space?

Comment: Recreate the tarball. Create a new tarball. Use something other than tar (which can do in-place updates).

Comment: for in-place updates I guess .zip files are a better choice than tar.

Comment: You aren't compressing the tar and you don't appear to be wanting to move it anywhere, so why not just use a backup directory and add/delete content as needed? And then perhaps consider `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, tar just doesn't support this. As an alternative, you could use zip, like this:

```
zip -r -FS myArchiveFile.zip dirToZip
```

Not "tar" like you asked for, but it does seem to work nicely. Another alternative would be to use 7z (the 7-zip archiver), which may give you better compression. The command-line options for this is obscure, but this works:

```
7z u -up1q0r2x2y2z1w2 myArchiveFile.7z dirToZip
```

(I found documentation for these 7z command-line options here: https://www.scottklement.com/p7zip/MANUAL/switches/update.htm. I don't know why it's so hard to find this documentation...).

If, for some reason, you don't want the compression provided by zip or 7z, there are ways to disable that too, so zip or 7z just create a file container kind of like tar does.

In the end, though, I think you should just re-create the archive each time. I suspect that the time saved doing the kind of synchronization you ask for is probably small.